# Deleting item in recyclerView does not reflect change in next Activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'am trying to delete a card having in recyclerview. The problem is when i click the delete button in my card the changes does not reflect the next activity. When i click Delete Button the textview and the imageview must change accordingly. But that is not happening.

this is my onclick in viewHolder. I have used Interface. :

```
      public void onClick(View view)
    {
        //get data from array list
        if(view.getId()==R.id.cont_root){

            if(itemClickCallback!=null) {
                itemClickCallback.onRootClick(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
        else{

            delete(getAdapterPosition());
        }

    }
}
```

This is my delete Method in the adapter :

```
public void delete( int position){

    listData.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount()-1);
}
```

This is my code when a Cardview is clicked .Card's name is Root.

```
    public void onRootClick(int p) {
    //adapter.setItemClickCallback(this);
    adapter.notifyItemChanged(p);
    ListItem item =(ListItem)listData.get(p);
    Intent i = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
    Bundle extras=new Bundle();
    extras.putString(EXTRA_QUOTE, item.getTitle());
    extras.putInt(EXTRA_ATTR,item.getImageResID());
    i.putExtra(BUNDLE_EXTRAS,extras);

    startActivity(i);

}
```

Note : i have not used interface method for deleting the element.

Please help. Iam new to Recyclerview. :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Methodes which relate to "what user is seeing" I can call them  (Layout side Methods) and they are :

- **getLayoutPosition()**
- **findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(int)**

The first one returns the view position in accordance to the Layout it self and not the adapter 
and the second one returns the **ViewHolder** for the item in the given position of the data set

In your code you are using what i can call (Adapter side Method)

- **getAdapterPosition()**

any changes using The (adapter side Methods) will not be reflected to Layout untill you use (the Layout side Methods)

Hope This helps

Comment: how do i use both of them at same time ? because i will need to change values in my adapter too.